# How to access a JSON file with one nested array in SQL Server and insert that nested array into a Table?

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, merge, nested

So, my question is basically this.

I have this stored procedure that uses a JSON file to insert or update a table `SERVICES` using `MERGE`.

The thing is, this JSON file has a nested array, which I must use to fill a second table `SERVICE_IMAGES` using the first table's `IdService` as a foreign key.

```
DECLARE @Services NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
    {
      "IdService": 10,
      "Name": "Nails",
      "Images_services": [
          {
            "Image_Id": "aaaaaa",          //This is unique ID
            "IdService": 10,              //This IdService should be the same as above
            "Image_Base64": "aaaaaa"     //This is a base64 Image 
          },          
          {
            "Image_Id": "bbbbb",     
            "IdService": 10,              
            "Image_Base64": "bbbbb"  
          },
          {
            "Image_Id": "ccccccccc",     
            "IdService": 10,              
            "Image_Base64": "ccccccccc"  
          }
      ]
   }
]
'
```

I already did the part where I insert or update the data into `Services` (`IdService, Name`) but I have no clue how to insert or update the `Service_Images` with the nested array `Images_services`.

For now I tried this but of course is not working:

```
SET @IdService = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
DECLARE @UNIQUEX UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @UNIQUEX = NEWID();

MERGE SERVICIO_IMAGENES AS TARGET
USING(
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(@JsonService, '$.Images_Service')
    WITH (
        Image_Id varchar(36) '$.Images_Service."Image_Id"',
        IdService INT '$.Image_Service."IdService"',
        Image_Base64 varchar(36) '$.Images_Service."Image_Base64"'
    ) AS JsonService
) AS SOURCE(Image_Id, IdService, Image_Base64)
ON TARGET.ID_SERVICE = @IdService
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TARGET.IMAGE_BASE64 = SOURCE.Image_Base64, TARGET.ID_IMAGE = @UNIQUEX, TARGET.ID_SERVICE = @IdService
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID_IMAGE, ID_SERVICE, IMAGE_BASE64) VALUES (@UNIQUEX, @IdService, SOURCE.Image_Base64);
```

The end result should looks something like this:

**SERVICES**

```
| IdService | Name  |
+-----------+-------+
|    10     | Nails |
```

**SERVICE_IMAGES**:

```
| Image_Id | IdService | Image_Base64 |
+----------+-----------+--------------+
|  aaaaaa  |    10     |  aaaaaa      |
|  bbbbbb  |    10     |  bbbbbb      |
|  cccccc  |    10     |  cccccc      |
```

Comment: Can you edit your sample so that it is valid JSON. At the very least you need closing `] } ]`. Then you have an array element which would usually be enclosed by something else

Comment: Omg, I'm so sorry for that mistake. Already fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different statement to parse the `$.Images_services` JSON array and this statement depends on the structure of the input JSON. For this specific case you need nested `OPENJSON()` calls with explicit schema (the `WITH` clause) and `AS JSON` option (to specify that the referenced property contains an inner JSON object or array). The following statements demonstrate this approach:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @Services NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
    {
      "IdService": 10,
      "Name": "Nails",
      "Images_services": [
          {
            "Image_Id": "aaaaaa",          
            "IdService": 10,              
            "Image_Base64": "aaaaaa"      
          },          
          {
            "Image_Id": "bbbbb",     
            "IdService": 10,              
            "Image_Base64": "bbbbb"  
          },
          {
            "Image_Id": "ccccccccc",     
            "IdService": 10,              
            "Image_Base64": "ccccccccc"  
          }
      ]
   }
]
'
```

Statement for services:

```
SELECT j1.IdService, j1.Name
FROM OPENJSON(@Services, '$') WITH (
   IdService int '$.IdService',
   Name varchar(100) '$.Name'
) j1
```

Statement for service images:

```
SELECT j2.*
FROM OPENJSON(@Services, '$') WITH (
   IdService int '$.IdService',
   Name varchar(100) '$.Name',
   Images_services nvarchar(max) '$.Images_services' AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.Images_services)
WITH (
   Image_Id varchar(36) '$.Image_Id',
   IdService int '$.IdService',
   Image_Base64 varchar(36) '$.Image_Base64'
) j2
```

Results:

```
IdService   Name
10          Nails

Image_Id    IdService   Image_Base64
aaaaaa      10          aaaaaa
bbbbb       10          bbbbb
ccccccccc   10          ccccccccc
```

Comment: @HarryAgámez If this answer solves your problem, you may accept it.